# What is Endora's last name?

Tags: bewitched

I have watched the TV Series *Bewitched* several times and each time we come to someone asking Endora's last name, she always says 'You could never pronounce it'.  I haven't watched the supplementary materials though, so does anyone know what Endora's surname was?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the TV series, almost none of the witches have surnames. This includes Samantha and her parents; Maurice and Endora.

Out of canon, in the 1965 authorised novelisation by Al Hine, Samantha's maiden name is [revealed](http://www.harpiesbizarre.com/faq.htm) to be "**Dobson**" however this appears to have been based on an [unused](http://www.sitcomsonline.com/boards/archive/index.php/t-72303.html) shooting script that references her father as being "*John Dobson, burned at the stake in York in 1538*".

This was later retconned with the introduction of Maurice.

[image]

Comment: No idea they had any novelizations. I may just read one. I think Montgomery was not just beautiful but a very good actress who would have been in many other shows/films had her career lasted. A lot of sad news about the cast, some shows and movies seem to have a "curse" associated with them -- I wonder how many of the cast are still around -- many of the actors would be significantly over 100, even 130 I think.

Answer (score 1):

Endora says her last name is "Waters" in episode "Eat at Mario's".

Comment: I believe you mean [Remember the Main](https://bewitched.fandom.com/wiki/Remember_the_Main) and in that instance she was using an *alias*. Still a good find though.

Comment: This perhaps reminds people of the most horrifyingly unfair question on Who Wants to be a Millionaire -- what was Carrol Brady's maiden name? You could be Isaac Newton and they still could find something easily he did not know and only someone in the Brady Bunch fan club, like its president, would have a shot of knowing this.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning of Season 5 Episode 18 (Samantha, The Bard)

Samantha seems to rhyme her last name:

> ... *Or my name is not **Sam Unser***...

Comment: According to [HarpiesBizarre](http://www.harpiesbizarre.com/scripts5.htm) (who have access to the script), the line is "*There must be a logical answer, or my name is not Sam**answer***" (e.g. she's mis-pronounced Samantha)